# Is there a name of this integral $\int_0^k \frac{n x^{-n-1}(1-x)^{-n-1}}{(x^{-n} + (1-x)^{-n} )^2} dx$?

Tags: integration

Is there a name of this Beta function-like integral?

$$\int_0^k \frac{x^{-n-1}(1-x)^{-n-1}}{(x^{-n} + (1-x)^{-n} )^2} dx$$

In case this is not standard, I'm interested in solution of it (for real $n$). If $n=1$ then this simplifies easily, but I'm interested in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Start multiplying top and bottom by $x^{2n}$
$$I_n=\int\frac{ x^{-n-1}(1-x)^{-n-1}}{\left(x^{-n}+(1-x)^{-n}\right)^2}\,dx=\int \frac{ x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n-1}}{\left(x^n+(1-x)^n\right)^2}\,dx$$
$$\frac x {1-x}=t\implies x=\frac t{1+t} \implies dx=\frac{dt}{(t+1)^2} \implies I_n=\int\frac{t^{n-1}}{\left(t^n+1\right)^2}\,dt$$ which seems to be very simple and does not have anything to do with the beta function.

Comment: Neat, thanks! Is this a standard trick? I wonder if it has a name :)

Comment: @FlightBooker It's a particular case of something called a [Linear Fractional Transformation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearFractionalTransformation.html).  A cool trick for sniffing out ways to simplify integrals is to do the substitution with arbitrary parameters, and then choose the constants so the result is as simple as possible.